# php $image = get_field( 'image' ) // if // else

Tags: php, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I need an inquiry if there is no image that an alternative image is used.

```
<?php $angebot_17 = get_field( 'angebot_17' ); ?>
           <?php if ( $angebot_17 ) : ?>
               <?php $post = $angebot_17; ?>
               <?php $image = get_field( 'image' ); ?>
                       <?php if ( $image ) { ?>
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                           <img width="300" height="300" src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $image['alt'] ); ?>" class="img-responsive product-img wp-post-image box_image" />
                           <?php $lager = get_field ('lager'); ?>
                           <?php if ( $lager) { ?>
                           <span class="goods_label" style="background-color: #00CC99;color: #ffffff;bottom:8px;border-color: #00CC99;">
                               <span>Versand aus Deutschland</span>
                           </span>
                           <?php } ?>
                       </a>
                       <?php } ?>
                       <?php else: ?>
                       <img width="300" height="300" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-Logo_512x512-4.png" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $image['alt'] ); ?>"  />
                       <span class="goods_label" style="background-color: red;color: #ffffff;bottom:8px;">
                               <span>Leider kein Bild vorhanden</span>
                           </span>
                       <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                       <?php endif; ?>
```

the crazy thing is that it works on four out of 18 images.
I think I have an error in the "else query" somewhere.
Because if I swap the defalut image with the actual product image, then it works .. but of course that is not meaningful;)

Comment: Ummmm ..... What? Please explain your issue  in a detailed concise manner

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working? What is the expected output?

Comment: Seriously not trying to be snarky, but this is a great example of why PHP is so difficult to manage.

Comment: oh sorry ...
although the "correct" images are available, the alternative images are shown to me.

Comment: How exactly is your image ACF field set up - i.e. what is in `$image`? You are using it as a string and an array, so some of those is wrong. Please show us what you get from `var_dump($image);`. Also, not related to this specific problem, but you are missing some of the `endif`s at the end (I presume you have them but just didn;t include them here?). Also you are mixing the use of `{` / `}`and `:` / `endif` - its not an error, but keeping everything consistent makes it easier to spot mistakes. You also don't need `<?php` `?>` on each line - you can have more than 1 line of code between them :)

Comment: ```` <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo '<pre>';
 var_dump( $image );
echo '</pre>'; ?>````  Output: string(66) "https://dein-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/ANYCUBIC-Chiron.jpg"

Comment: that's probably the problem that i mixed it all up ...

Comment: OK, thats not very clear because its not formatted as code, but I am guessing that means that it is just returning the image url? Is that what you have set it up as in the ACF field?

Comment: what I just do not understand that this works with some pictures?!? I'll give you the link to my endless construction site ^^ https://dein-3d.com/3d_drucker_angebote/juli-2020/

Comment: in acf I have "Image" as the field type and the return format: Image array.
Alternatively, I have "Text single line" as the field type. To try out whether this is possible I would have to restart my import and assign a new field type.

Comment: Could it be that I somehow forgot a `<? php else:?>` or set it incorrectly?
If I select `<? Php else:?>` In the editor, then it refers to the first "if query" (`<? Php if ($angebote_18):?>`) ... but it should actually refer to "`<? php if ($ image) {?>`" react ?? https://ibb.co/gJCfHVP

Comment: Image array doesn't add up to what you shows in the var_dump. Can you add the var_dump *before* `<?php if ( $image ) { ?>` and then edit your question to add what is displayed using code formatting, so we can actually see it  :) Also, is this code inside the WP Loop (e.g. ` while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`) and if so, can you also add that to the question.

Comment: when i wrote: `<?php echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $image ); echo '</pre>'; ?>
                       <?php if ( $image ) { ?>`nothing is displayed at this point ...

Comment: it's not a loop yet ... this is my next construction site, because i always have changing contributions that are shown here. Currently there are 18. So I have the same code 18 times in a row ... the only thing that changes is: `angebot_XXX`

Comment: If nothing is being displayed at that point, then that's why your `if ( $image ) ` clause is failing - `get_field` is returning nothing so the `else` is getting executed. I can't tell you why the field is empty though - Are you sure it is set up properly and that the image is added in the correct field? Are all your `angebot_XXX` in the same page/post?

Comment: _“nothing is displayed at this point”_ - it is _impossible_ to get “nothing” from a var_dump. Even for a not even existing variable, you would get `null`, and for an empty string you’d still get `string(0) ""`

Comment: Why do you have `wp_reset_postdata(); ` inside your else statement..

Comment: @CBroe I assumed they meant that nothing was being displayed inside the `if` when they said "at this point" after the if condition. (But nothing about this question makes a lot of sense :) )

Comment: @FluffyKitten I was referring to Karsten’s own _“when i wrote […]”_ comment above. That indicated the var_dump was placed before the if, and if _that_ displays “nothing”, then that would indicate it does not even reach that var_dump part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it works!!!

I wrote the whole code again "cleanly"!

Thanks for all the support!

```php
<?php
    $angebot_1 = get_field( 'angebot_1' );
    if ($angebot_1) {
        $post = $angebot_1;
        $image = get_field( 'image' );

        if ($image) {
            echo '
                <img
                width="300"
                height="300"
                src="' . esc_url( $image['url'] ) .'"
                alt="' . esc_attr( $image['alt'] ) . '"
                class="img-responsive product-img wp-post-image box_image" /> ';

            $lager = get_field ('lager');
            if ($lager) {
                echo '<span
                        class="goods_label"
                        style="background-color: #00CC99;color: #ffffff;bottom:8px;border-color: #00CC99;">
                    <span>Versand aus Deutschland</span>
                </span> ';
                }

            }
            else {
                echo '<img
                        width="300"
                        height="300"
                        src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-Logo_512x512-4.png"
                        alt="'. esc_attr( $image['alt'] ).'"  /> ';
                echo '<span
                            class="goods_label" style="background-color: red;color: #ffffff;bottom:8px;">
                                <span>Leider kein Bild vorhanden</span>
                            </span> ';
            }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

Comment: If you have a new question you should create a new question all together